# Icon Menu in Genexus 18

Tags: genexus

In GeneXus 18 I need to put icon class (as fa fa-pen) in menus.
But I can't find  the Icon Class property.

I'm trying to do that in the browser not using DataProvider.

Until Genexus 17 the Class Icon property appeared.
Thank you